# Not able to set focus on the first edittext field?

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberformatexception

**I am not able to set focus on the first edittext field (among other 3 below it).Code is:**

```
k1_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k1_editText);
k1_e.requestFocusFromTouch();
try{
k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("logtag", "Exception: " + e.toString());
}
k2_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k2_editText);
try{
    k2=Float.parseFloat(k2_e.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("logtag", "Exception: " + e.toString());
}
al_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_editText);
try{
    al=Float.parseFloat(al_e.getText().toString());
}catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("logtag", "Exception: " + e.toString());
}
alconst_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_const_editText);
try{
    al_const=Float.parseFloat(alconst_e.getText().toString()); 
}catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("logtag", "Exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

---

**when app is executed on emulator it automatically sets focus to last edittext field and an exception is thrown as:**

```
12-29 08:10:05.241: E/logtag(769): Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
12-29 08:10:05.261: E/logtag(769): Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
12-29 08:10:05.261: E/logtag(769): Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
12-29 08:10:05.271: E/logtag(769): Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
```

---

**what is the error.I am a beginner.pls help**

Comment: k1_e.getText().toString() returns "" which cant converted to Float

Comment: edittext.requestFocus(); programaticaly write this.. why use touchfocus..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your k1_e.getText().toString() returns `String` which cant converted Float

**Try this for all:**

Do this, make 
`int flag = 0;` gobal to your class. 
and when you getview executed for the first time then make the flag as 1;

**Like this:**

```
int flag = 0;

  getView()
{
if(flag == 0)
{
k1_e.requestFocusFromTouch();flag = 1;
}
  string abc = k1_e.getText().toString()
        if(abc != null && !abc.equals(""))
        {
         k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString());
        }
    else
    {
      k1 = 0.0;
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem is "abc" will be null because i am not able to get focus on k1 edittext box. can u help me with that

Comment: are you using k1_e.requestFocusFromTouch(); in your custom view??

Comment: now i can input data to k1 but the field is not getting focused. any idea on that?

Comment: you mean if(flag == 0)
{
k1_e.requestFocusFromTouch();flag = 1;
} code not executed properly

Comment: use requestFocus() instead of requestFocusFromTouch() and let me know